# OR tools CVRP reload using single vehicle

Tags: java, or-tools

Following the python examples [here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/cvrp_reload.py)

I am trying to build the same feature in java which is - load the stuff and deliver to customers and if the next demand is more than the left over capacity then go to depot and reload. All this is happening without any time constraints, however there is only 1 vehicle in my case. The problem is that the solution is null for many cases.

For example: demand: `[0, -30, -30, -30, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18]` with a vehicle capacity of 30 results into null. However, the same demand with different vehicle capacity works fine like `-18`, `36`, `48`, `96`.

The first demand is 0 coz that's the start location.

Here is the code that I am using:

```java
final OrDataModel data = buildDataModel();

RoutingIndexManager manager = new RoutingIndexManager(data.distanceMatrix.length, data.vehicleNumber, data.depot);

RoutingModel routing = new RoutingModel(manager);

final int transitCallbackIndex =
routing.registerTransitCallback((long fromIndex, long toIndex) -> {
  int fromNode = manager.indexToNode(fromIndex);
  int toNode = manager.indexToNode(toIndex);
  return data.distanceMatrix[fromNode][toNode];
});

routing.setArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transitCallbackIndex);
routing.addDimension(transitCallbackIndex, 0, 1000000, true, "Distance");
RoutingDimension distanceDimension = routing.getDimensionOrDie("Distance");
distanceDimension.setGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100);

final int demandCallbackIndex = routing.registerUnaryTransitCallback(
  (long fromIndex) -> {
  // Convert from routing variable Index to user NodeIndex.
  int fromNode = manager.indexToNode(fromIndex);
  return data.demands[fromNode];
});

routing.addDimension(demandCallbackIndex, data.vehicleCapacity, data.vehicleCapacity, true, "Capacity");
RoutingDimension capacityDimension = routing.getDimensionOrDie("Capacity");

//No penalty in case multi-trip visit is skipped when not required
for(int i = 1; i <= data.multiTrips - 1; i++) {
  int fromNode = manager.indexToNode(i);
  routing.addDisjunction(new long[] { fromNode }, 0);
}

// Setting first solution heuristic.
RoutingSearchParameters searchParameters =
  main.defaultRoutingSearchParameters()
  .toBuilder()
  .setFirstSolutionStrategy(FirstSolutionStrategy.Value.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
  .setLocalSearchMetaheuristic(LocalSearchMetaheuristic.Value.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
  .setTimeLimit(Duration.newBuilder().setSeconds(1).build())
  .build();

// Solve the problem.
Assignment solution = routing.solveWithParameters(searchParameters);

if(solution != null) {
   printSolution(data, routing, manager, solution);
} else {
  System.out.print("no results");
}
```

```
private static OrDataModel buildDataModel() {
    
    List<Long> volumes = new ArrayList<>();
    List<double[]> locations = new ArrayList<>();
    readCsvFile(volumes, locations);
    
    double totalVolume = LCollectionUtils.sumDoubleProperty(volumes, volume -> volume);
    
    int maxCapacity = 30;
    
    int multiTrips = calculateMultiTrips(totalVolume, maxCapacity);
    
    List<double[]> multiTripLocations = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < multiTrips; i++) {
        multiTripLocations.add(new double[] { 24.3653, 54.7136 });
    }
    
    List<double[]> allLocations = new ArrayList<double[]>(multiTripLocations);
    allLocations.addAll(locations);
    double[][] matrix = new double[allLocations.size()][];
    matrix = allLocations.toArray(matrix);
    
    long[][] distanceMatrix = buildDistanceMatrix(matrix, multiTrips);
    long[][] timeMatrix = buildTimeMatrix(matrix, multiTrips);
    long[] demands = fillDemands(multiTrips, matrix.length, volumes, maxCapacity);
    
    long[][] timeWindows = fillTimeWindow(allLocations.size(), multiTrips);
    
    return OrDataModel.from(matrix, distanceMatrix, timeMatrix, demands, allLocations.size(), multiTrips, maxCapacity, timeWindows, totalVolume);
}

private static long[] fillDemands(int minimumMultiTrips, int numberOfLocations, List<Long> allVolumes, long vehicleCapacity) {
    
    long[] demands = new long[numberOfLocations];
    
    //first demand is at depot so 0
    demands[0] = 0;
    
    int index;
    for(index = 1; index < minimumMultiTrips; index++) {
        demands[index] = (long)-vehicleCapacity;
    }
    
    for(int j = 0; j < allVolumes.size(); j++) {
        demands[index] = allVolumes.get(j);
        index++;
    }
    
    return demands;
}


private static int calculateMultiTrips(double totalVolume, int capacity) {
    double remainder = totalVolume % capacity;
    double quotient = totalVolume / capacity;
    double multiTrip = remainder == 0 ? quotient : quotient + 1;
    return (int)multiTrip;
}

private static long[][] buildDistanceMatrix(double[][] locations, int minimumMultiTrips) {

    long[][] distanceData = new long[locations.length][locations.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        
        LatLng fromLatLng = new LatLng().lat(locations[i][0]).lng(locations[i][1]);

        for (int j = 0; j < locations.length; j++) {

            if (i == j) {
                distanceData[i][j] = 0;
            }
            
            else if(i < minimumMultiTrips && j < minimumMultiTrips) {
                distanceData[i][j] = 100000;
            }
            
            else {
                LatLng toLatLng = new LatLng().lat(locations[j][0]).lng(locations[j][1]);
                LatLngQueryDataFetcher distanceFetcher = new HaversineDistanceFetcher(30, 1.25);
                sh.locus.pjp.server.model.distance.TimeDistancePair response = distanceFetcher.fetch(fromLatLng, toLatLng);
                distanceData[i][j] = response.getDistance();
            }
        }
    }

    return distanceData;
}
```

The code is simple. Reading demand, lat and long from a csv file. Hardcoded the homebase location for this sample. Built the distance and time matrix but only using distance matrix. What possibly am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

note AddDisjunction take index not node so basically your code :

```java
    //No penalty in case multi-trip visit is skipped when not required
    for(int i = 1; i <= data.multiTrips - 1; i++) {
        int fromNode = manager.indexToNode(i);
        routing.addDisjunction(new long[] { fromNode }, 0);
    }
```

is wrong you need the opposite

```java
    //No penalty in case multi-trip visit is skipped when not required
    for(int i = 1; i <= data.multiTrips - 1; i++) {
        int fromIndex = manager.nodeToIndex(i);
        routing.addDisjunction(new long[] { fromIndex }, 0);
    }
```

Comment: didn't help. Thanks though!